# Name of a certain type of subgroup of general/special linear groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, symplectic-linear-algebra, general-linear-group

Let $V_n\simeq V_m^{1} \otimes V_m^{2} \cdots \otimes V_m^{k}$ be an $n=m^k$-dimensional vector space over some field $F$, and $\textrm{GL}_n(F)$ the general linear group over that vector space. The superscripts are here only for bookkeeping. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by permutations of the $V_m^i$ factors and elements $g$ in $\textrm{GL}_n(F)$ that act only on the factors. That is, $g = g_1 \otimes g_2 \otimes \cdots g_k$, where $g_i \in \textrm{GL}_n^i$.
Such subgroups naturally arise in cases where the large group acts on a set that is invariant under `local operations' and permutations.

Is there a name for such a subgroup, or any references for this? Is $H$ an outer semidirect product between $\textrm{GL}_m^{1}\times \textrm{GL}_m^2 \times\cdots \textrm{GL}_m^{k}$ and a group isomorphic to $S_n$? Are such subgroups maximal?

One can also make a similar construction, but with $\textrm{GL}_n(F)$ replaced by $\textrm{SL}_n(F)$, $\textrm{SP}_{2n}(F)$ and similiar groups (think $S_n$), and/or replacing the tensor product with the direct product.

Comment: This is a wreath product. | BTW it seems like a physicist thing to label your $V$s with the dimension $m$. I think a typical mathematician would write $V_1\otimes\cdots\otimes V_k$ and say each $V_i$ has dimension $m$. (Just observing.) Also you should say $g_i\in GL$ not $g_i\in V$.

Comment: You're completely right, I messed up with the $g_i$'s, and it seems my background is shining through!